# Inconsistent query results from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Today we have spotted a strange behavior in SQL queries (we use MySQL v5.6.36 and InnoDB).

Take this query:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*)  FROM `inventory` WHERE `user_id` = 12345;
```

It returns the following result:

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      495 |
+----------+
```

But then when a following query is run:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*)  FROM `inventory` WHERE `user_id` = 12345 AND list_type = 3;
```

We get:

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     1263 |
+----------+
```

As you can see the result count is bigger when query is restricted which should not happen. What could be the cause of this? It happens in master database only while both replication databases show the correct results. We suspect corrupted indexes. How to prevent such errors in the future?

Any other conditions apart from `list_type` return invalid (too high) counts as well.

Comment: Maybe the DB was populated between queries.

Comment: No, this is certainly not the case (meaning we've checked it).

Comment: InnoDB or MyISAM? (Not that I have a solution either way)

Comment: For InnoDB tables, the row count is only a rough estimate used in SQL optimization. (This is also true if the InnoDB table is partitioned.) Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html I also noticed a while ago that I get different count results on the same db.(my db was few millions rows, and yeah the query was an estimation) in your case it's not a good estimation though :D

Comment: Have you tried running analyse on the table? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: @Keloo, the row count in SHOW TABLE STATUS or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES is an estimate. The result from SELECT COUNT(*) should be the accurate count.

Comment: This other question on DBA seems to show a similar case. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/172294/frequent-corrupt-indexes-in-mysql-5-6-is-this-a-mysql-bug The problem was solved by one user by disabling index merge optimizations (see answer on that thread from Tom Wu).

Comment: @Sam, yes, I've followed the steps suggested by Collector below.

Answer (score 5):

Inconsistent results could mean corrupt database or (if you're lucky) a corrupt index. Try to launch the above queries without using an index and see what you get:

```
SELECT count(*)  FROM `inventory` USE INDEX () WHERE `user_id` = 12345;
SELECT count(*)  FROM `inventory` USE INDEX () WHERE `user_id` = 12345 AND list_type = 3;
```

In case this is only an index you could try

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE `inventory`;
```

Which recreates the tables and indexes and then does **ANALYZE** on it. That's because InnoDB doesn't support **REPAIR TABLE**.
Another option could be to try and add an identical index and then dropping the original index.

To perform checks on a table you could also use **CHECK TABLE** but if you wish to check the entire database you could try

```
mysqlcheck --login-path=credentials --databases db_name
```

and to optimize all tables

```
mysqlcheck --login-path=credentials --optimize --databases db_name
```

Looking at the error logs of the server might give you a hint on whether this was a hardware issue or some MySQL bug you've ran into.

In case your actual database is corrupt, it'll make sense to check the hardware and then try to see what has been corrupt and how to restore it by comparing to a recent backup.

Answer (score -4):

Sometimes SQL can't handle well the 'null' value.
Try this:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*)  FROM inventory WHERE (user_id = 12345 AND user_id is not null) AND (list_type = 3 AND list_type is not null);
```

If it doesn't work, try to replace the '*' to the primary key.
For example:

```
mysql> SELECT count(user_id)  FROM inventory WHERE (user_id = 12345 AND user_id is not null) AND (list_type = 3 AND list_type is not null);
```

Although if `user_id` can't be 'null', in this case you don't need to test for that.